# How do I prevent windows opening on one of my desktops?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors and a tv screen connected to my computer. The tv is angled so I can watch it in bed but is facing away from my desk (and usually switched off). Sometimes applications open on the monitor and I have to fiddle around with the "Move" menu option to bring them back to one of the screens I can see.

I don't want to disable the tv as I will just have to reenable it when I want to watch something on it, so how can I prevent applications opening on the tv?

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck by going in to display settings and manually setting the other screen to primary, this should switch one screen with the other of where all applications open by default.

The other thing is, Windows has a few new cool shortcut buttons. You can use the following keys to help with multiple monitors:

<kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> = Snaps to the left half, then Move one screen to the left.

<kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> = Snaps to the right half, then Move one screen to the right.

<kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> = Maximise

<kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> = Restore, then Minimize

Lastly, you can use a few multi screen management software such as [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) - however, I am not personally a fan of these.

Comment: many applications ignore the primary monitor feature (or possibly save the last screen the application was on, or alternatively get confused when you connect or disconnect monitors and open on a different on)

windows + <- doesn't work for speedfan which is the application that broke the camel's back this morning (although windows + up or down do work with it).

Comment: Try pressing it a few times (made a mistake and am going to edit now)... but if the application uses a custom form, it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage the exact window position, size, transparency and other rules for each programs with a decent window manager.

2 recommendations:

Eusing's **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)** (freeware)

**[Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/)** (Shareware, $49.95, 60 days evaluation period)

*clearly my favorite, this program is pretty much a 'must have' in a multi monitor environment.*